# Problema al leer el final de un archivo usando .eof()

Tags: c++, vectores, fstream

Estoy intentando leer las coordenadas x e y escritas dentro de un fichero hasta el final. Para después introducir cada una en un vector.
Me falla cuando introduzco .eof() dentro del while.

La salida muestra; request for member 'eof' in 'nombre_coords', which is of non-class type 'const

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

//Nombres del Fichero
const char nombre_coords[]="2PECSepiembre2017Coordenadas.txt";

int main(){
//Vectores
vector<double>vX;
vector<double>vY;
//Donde almacenar datos del fichero
double coordX;
double coordY;

ifstream Fichero(nombre_coords, ios::in);
if(!Fichero)
{
    cout<<"Algo incorrecto has hecho";
    return 1;

}
while(!nombre_coords.eof()){ //Aqui se produce el fallo
    Fichero>>coordX;
    Fichero>>coordY;
    vX.push_back(coordX);
    vY.push_back(coordY);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: No sera `!Fichero.eof()` en lugar de `!nombre_coords.eof()`. Nota: Es mucho
mejor usar en la condicion: `Fichero>>coordX && Fichero>>coordY`.

Comment: Sí, me di cuenta tarde. Muchas gracias. Por cierto, ¿Por qué es mejor de esa manera en la condición?

Comment: Porque si hay un error en la lectura será falso. Puedes tener un error en la
lectura y `eof()` no te dira nada. Nota2: `Fichero>>coordX>>coordY` es mejor, te
ahorras el `&&`.

Comment: Vale, ya lo entendí. Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: @Luther, esto está resuelto entonces, solo había que reemplazar !Fichero.eof() y cerrar la llave } al final?.